# Problem with Wordpress' div class="Post", "Entry" and "postmetadata"

Tags: class, post, html

Im having trouble with my codes in wordpress. You can see my problem in the link below:

http://i1204.photobucket.com/albums/bb409/bendaggers/help-1.png

as you can see, i'm having trouble sticking them all together

**the CSS codes are here:**

```
.post{
padding: 10px 0 0 0px;
background-image: url(images/toppost.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


.entry{
background-image:url(images/ContentBG.png);
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding:0 0 0 0;
background-position: bottom;
}

.postmetadata {
clear: both;
background-image: url(images/post-footer.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:118px;
}
```

**the php codes are here:**

```
<div id="container">

    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(); ?></div>

            <p class="postmetadata">
                <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>



    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

can you help me with my problem? its taking me so looong to solve this one coz im still a newbie in wordpress.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding to your classes:

```
.post{
padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
background-image: url(images/toppost.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


.entry{
background-image:url(images/ContentBG.png);
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding:0 5px;
background-position: bottom;
}

.postmetadata {
clear: both;
background-image: url(images/post-footer.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:118px;
padding:0 5px;
}
```

Comment: try to add !imprtant to each padding: padding:0 5px !important;

Comment: I can't help without the html code of your page. Can you provide a link so i can see the problem?

Comment: I posted the HTML/PHP codes above, you can take a look at them. Sorry I'm working in my local computer using Xampp.

Comment: Bobby, you pulled it! Thank you very much for your help. been staring blanking in my monitor for an hour with this stupid issue. Thanks again for you help.